# How to find out & set policy in Window Server 2016. To search in security event viewer for users accidentally delete shared network folder?

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-event-log

I am trying to set GPO so that I can search user in event viewer who accidentally deleted the share drive in the network.

What other event IDs list can I search so that I know which category it belongs to?

Example 4624 = logon

[image]

I had tried the below steps however, when i do a search filter, it did not shows the deleted item Event ID#4663, instead it shows others access.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply, I had tried the steps below.

Comment: Keep in mind that you first need to set an audit policy. There is also an tool which can do this AD Audit Plus. http://woshub.com/tracking-files-deletion-using-audit-policy-and-mssql/

Answer (score 0):

You first need to

1. Enable File and Folder Access Auditing Policy
2. Now you need to configure auditing in the properties of the share
   network folder you
   want to track
3. Now, if the user deletes any file or folder in the
   shared network folder, the File System -> Audit Success file delete
   event appears in the Security log with Event ID 4663 from the
   Microsoft Windows security auditing source.
   Open the Event Viewer mmc console (eventvwr.msc), expand the Windows
   Logs -> Security section. Enable event log filter by the EventID
   4663.

http://woshub.com/tracking-files-deletion-using-audit-policy-and-mssql/

Comment: Thanks for the input. :)

Comment: On StackOverflow pls vote up if useful.

Answer (score 0):

This link has all the information you need to enable auditing:

https://system32.eventsentry.com/security/event/5144

https://system32.eventsentry.com/security/auditing

This site will also give you more information on other events, such as 4624.

I hope you understand that you cannot enable auditing retroactively, so this will of course only work for future activity/events.

Comment: Thanks for the info. :)

Comment: On StackOverflow pls vote up if useful.